# How to use After order place event in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

After order place get customer attribute value and set order status in Magento 2.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: "if customer is not approve" means ??

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Yes if customer not approve order are pending otherwise order are processing

Comment: Ok i upload answer please check let me know.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use observer and plugin both, here I am going to use observer.

1. Create a file events.xml on following path **Magento_Root\app\code\Test\Extension\etc\events.xml**

And put following code inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="Test_Extension_Order_Created" instance="Test\Extension\Observer\ChangeOrderStatus" />
 </event>
</config>
```

2. Now create another file on following path **Magento_Root\app\code\Test\Extension\Observer\ChangeOrderStatus.php** and put below code inside it.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Test\Extension\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

   class ChangeOrderStatus implements ObserverInterface
   {   
     public function __construct    (             
      \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order   
     ) 
   {        
    $this->order = $order;     
   }

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
     $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
     $order = $this->order->load($orderId); 
     $orderState = Order::STATUS_PENDING;
     $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATUS_PENDING);
     $order->save();
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: order status pending is not working showing this error  **Error: Undefined class constant 'STATE_PENDING'**

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create observer into events.xml
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

After that, you need to create Observer file at following location.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{   
    public function __construct    (             
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order   
    ) 
    {        
        $this->order = $order;     
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $order = $this->order->load($orderId); 
        $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $order->save();
     }
}
```

Comment: how to set order status pending if customer is not approve.

Comment: In your situation only registered customers can place orders or guest checkout is enable? If guest checkout is enabled then your attribute value will blank.

Comment: How to set order status pending ?

Answer (score 0):

create events.xml
app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="vendor_module_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

Create Observer :- Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{   
    protected $customerFactory;
    
    protected $order;
   
    public function __construct    (             
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory   
    ) 
    {        
        $this->order = $order;  
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $customer = $order->getCustomerId();
        if($customerId)
        {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
            $isApprove = $customer->getIsApprove()   //here you can get customer attribute value
            if($isApprove)
            {
                   $order = $this->order->load($orderId); 
                   $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
                   $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING); 
            } else {
                   $order = $this->order->load($orderId); 
                   $orderState = Order::STATE_PENDING;
                   $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PENDING); 
            }
        }
        $order->save();
     }
}
```

Comment: order status pending is not working showing this error **Error: Undefined class constant 'STATE_PENDING'**